# FollowSymlinks .htaccess Rewrite Rule 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

My real URL is:

www.mysite.com/site/index.php

I need:

www.mysite.com/home.html

I write in the .htaccess:

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*)/home.html$ /site/index.php
```

But go to 404 Error

Any help?

Tk.

UPDATE:

Have any effect that the domain is actually: www.my-site.com  ??

UPDATE:

I save in www.my-site.com and change for this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^home\.html$ site/index.php
</IfModule>
```

But no work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *pattern* part of the [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive matches on the *path* of the request (eg. /my/request/), the host and query string is not included. Also note that in a *.htaccess* context the leading slash is not included in the *pattern*.

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^home\.html$ site/index.php
```

Comment: I change for this:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^home\.html$ site/index.php
    </IfModule>

But no working

The file .htaccess is save in www.mysite.com/site/

Answer (score 1):

in my server, i changed on `httpd.conf` in Apache

`AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

And Work it!

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments:

> The file .htaccess is save in www.mysite.com/site/

This means, with the current pattern you can access `www.mysite.com/site/anything/home.html` which will be rewritten to `www.mysite.com/site/site/index.php`

You should put the `.htaccess` in the document root and, as already suggested, remove this part from the pattern: `(.*)/`

Answer (score 0):

This site is hosted by godaddy.com, the server run in Windows over IIS, so, the rule have to be write in a web.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
      <match url="^home\.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="site/index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Unbelievable!!